# How to check SharePoint Installed in "SharePoint integration Mode"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, service

Is Reporting Service Integration Mode available in the server farm or not. How to check?

Environment:

- SharePoint 2013 Enterprice
- SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What SharePoint version do you use? What SQL version do you use? Is your SharePoint farm single server farm, or is SharePoint and SQL on different machines?

Comment: Sharepoint version : 2013 enterprise,sql version :2008 R2 ,Sql is in different server ,SharePoint is single server farm,

Answer (score 3):

Go to SharePoint Central Administration >> System Settings >> Manage Services on server, and check if SQL reporting services is there or not

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but according to [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492257.aspx) SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services integration combination is not supported. So you could not have Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode.

Comment: can we have another option for reporting service install stand alone in SP 2013 @ECM4D

Comment: That depends on why do you need Reporting Services Integration in SharePoint. Reporting Services Integration feature basically allows you only store Report, Data Source files and etc. in SharePoint library and use web parts if you need that. When you have Native mode, you can store this data in RS web application and have direct link from SharePoint site to the Reports. In Native mode you still can access SharePoint data in your Reports. So sometimes you can choose not to bother about Integration mode, and change your requirements how you will access your reports and data.